# Custom TableViewCell will not show created content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with four views in it

```
@interface SuggestingTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesTwo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesThree;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesFour;

@end
```

The `SuggestedSeriesView` is just a subclass of UIView with a bit of element placing code in it

When the DataSource method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called i create the cell like so

```
Genre *genre = [self.genres objectAtIndex:numberOfGenreIndex];
NSArray *series = self.seriesByGenres[genre.name];
cellIdentifier = suggestionCell;
SuggestingTableViewCell *tempCell = (SuggestingTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
Series *ser1 = series[0];
tempCell.seriesOne = [[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:tempCell.seriesOne.bounds
                                     andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE_URL : ser1.imageURL,
                                                     JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser1.title}];
.... Continue creating serirsTwo/Three/Four..
```

But for some reason the content isn't showing.

1. I have the `Delegate` and `DataSource` connected
2. All the views are wired out to the cell's subclass
3. when i log the cell's content view, i can see all four of `SuggestedSeriesView` in the stack of the cell.

> ```
> "<SuggestedSeriesView: 0x7997b2b0; frame = (161 2; 157 197); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer:
> ```
>
> 0x7997b3e0>>",
>
> ```
> "<SuggestedSeriesView: 0x79980090; frame = (161 201; 157 197); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer:
> ```
>
> 0x7997a250>>",
>
> ```
> "<SuggestedSeriesView: 0x799769b0; frame = (2 201; 157 197); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer:
> ```
>
> 0x79981d00>>",
>
> ```
> "<SuggestedSeriesView: 0x79976a20; frame = (2 2; 157 197); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer:
> ```
>
> 0x7997a4f0>>"

4. I'm using Storyboards (BTW, if i color the Views in the storyboard i can see is it the simulator)

Thanks for any help,

**EDIT1**

Just messing around with the code ,if i change the code in `tabelView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` to `addSubView` instead of the equal sign everything works as expected

```
Series *ser1 = series[0];
[tempCell.seriesOne addSubview:[[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:tempCell.seriesOne.bounds
                                                            andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE_URL : ser1.imageURL,
                                                                            JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser1.title}]];
tempCell.seriesOne.clipsToBounds = YES;
.... Continue creating serirsTwo/Three/Four..
```

Dunno if that helps

**EDIT 2**

Ok, i think i'm going a bit crazy.

I have been playing around with my code, login a few situations and trying to understand why this is happening

I have this log:

```
Series *ser1 = series[0];
SuggestedSeriesView *suggSer1 = [[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:tempCell.seriesOne.bounds
                                                             andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE : ser1.imageData,
                                                                             JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser1.title}];
tempCell.seriesOne = suggSer1;
NSLog(@"%@", tempCell.seriesOne.subviews);
```

And this is the log

> ```
> "<UIImageView: 0x7ae31530; frame = (0 0; 297 197); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ae216f0>>",
> "<UIView: 0x7ae15ab0; frame = (0 0; 297 197); alpha = 0.45; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ae03a70>>",
> "<UILabel: 0x7ae0f2f0; frame = (19 157; 53.2568 17.145); text = '5 FACTS!'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7c634410>>"
> ```

As you can see all of the content exists! but for some reason it is not showing...

Comment: You have not shown enough to get proper answer

Comment: What can i add to further explain the problem?

Comment: Im not sure but this is a custom cell with custom views and custom models. for example its not clear what is the datasource

Comment: Yes it's a custom cell (with four views in it). Every view that it init places a Image and a label inside the view

Answer (score 0):

This may have nothing to do with it, but try making your IBOutlet properties weak instead of strong.